# How to Save Data by Component In cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to store data by using component in cakephp

**My component name is UpdatedateComponent:**

```
<?php
class UpdatedateComponent extends Component
    {   
        public function clean($string)
            {
                $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
                return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
            }

        public function updatedatefunction($proid,$edit,$model1,$model2,$field)
            {
                if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
                    $this->$model1->$model2->id = $edit;
                    $this->request->data[$model2][$field] = $proid;
                    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
                    $date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
                    $this->request->data[$model2]['cganges'] = $date;
                    $this->$model1->$model2->save($this->request->data);
                } 
            }
    }
?>
```

My controller name is  `SlidermasterControler`

I am calling this component by like this

> $this->Updatedate->updatedatefunction($proid,1,'Slidermaster','Homesliderchangemaster','slidermaster_id');

but data not being stored

Comment: Not sure what answer you expect, so: "Permission granted".

Answer (score 0):

You can't access models directly from the component, since components are meant to perform some common tasks for controllers.

To access a model from within a component you need to first access the controller instance and then the respective model.

```
$this->controller->ModelOne->ModelTwo-save($data);
```